# Group spark type-safe aggregations by multiple keys

Tags: apache-spark

In the snippet below the second aggregation fails (not surprising) with:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to spark_test.Record

```
package spark_test

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Encoder, Encoders, SparkSession}
import org.scalatest.FunSuite

case class Record(k1: String, k2: String, v: Long) extends Serializable

class MyAggregator extends Aggregator[Record, Long, Long] {
  override def zero: Long = 0
  override def reduce(b: Long, a: Record): Long = a.v + b
  override def merge(b1: Long, b2: Long): Long = b1 + b2
  override def finish(reduction: Long): Long = reduction
  override def bufferEncoder: Encoder[Long] = Encoders.scalaLong
  override def outputEncoder: Encoder[Long] = Encoders.scalaLong
}

class TypeSafeAggTest extends FunSuite {

  lazy val spark: SparkSession = {
    SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("spark test")
      .getOrCreate()
  }

  test("agg flow") {

    import spark.sqlContext.implicits._

    val df: DataFrame = Seq(
      ("a", "b", 1),
      ("a", "b", 1),
      ("c", "d", 1)
    ).toDF("k1", "k2", "v")

    val aggregator = new MyAggregator()
      .toColumn.name("output")

    df.as[Record]
      .groupByKey(_.k1)
      .agg(aggregator)
      .show(truncate = false)   // < --- works #######

    df.as[Record]
      .groupBy($"k1", $"k2") 
      .agg(aggregator)
      .show(truncate = false)  // < --- fails runtime #######
  }
}
```

There is a very simplistic example page from the official docs, but it doesn't cover using typesafe aggregators with grouping (so it's unclear whether such case is supported).

http://spark.apachecn.org/docs/en/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#type-safe-user-defined-aggregate-functions

Is there a way to group by multiple keys when using Spark type-safe aggregators?

Comment: ".groupByKey(v=> (v.k1,v.k2))" ?

Comment: Indeed! Can you pls make it an answer so I can mark as resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use such construction:

```
.groupByKey(v=> (v.k1,v.k2))
```

Comment: For more details on why this only works with `groupByKey()` and not `groupBy()`, see the upstream bug at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16474